# The button responsible for the NuGet packages in Visual Studio 2022 has disappeared

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 to develop an application, and I need to add NuGet packages to my project. However, I'm having trouble finding the tab or option within the Visual Studio 2022 environment where I can add NuGet packages. I've tried searching through the menus of Visual Studio but haven't found the appropriate option. I would appreciate help finding the correct way to add NuGet packages in Visual Studio 2022.

I've attempted to solve the issue by exploring the various tabs in Visual Studio, but I got lost because I'm fairly new to this environment. I couldn't find the specific tab or option to add NuGet packages. Could someone please guide me on how to navigate and locate this feature in Visual Studio?

Comment: Solution explorer, expand your project: there should be a "dependencies" node. Right click there should give you "manage nuget packages"